# Calculatng the time difference between two times (using the next specific ID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here is an example of the table:

```
ProductID    TransID    TransSubID    TimeID (HH:MM:SS)
111          58           2           10:00:00 
251          185         10           11:00:00
111          80           0           12:00:00
538          117          1           13:00:00
111          80           0           14:00:00
```

I need a query to return the elapsed time for `ProductID 111` between `TransID 58` , `TransSubID 2` and the next record for `ProductID 111` ,   `TransID 80`  ,  `TransSubID 0`. The correct result would be `2 hours`. `4 hours` would be incorrect.

Comment: So there are 2 rows for `ProductID 111 ,  TransID 80 ,  TransSubID 0`, which do you want to be considered in the calc.?

Comment: We are not going to do all the work for you. I do have a hint though: You should give the `lag` and `lead` functions a try. You can use them to get the next row.

Comment: @SoulTrain - The next occurrence following TransID 58.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Thanks. I'll look into those functions.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you to the point where you have the next timeid value in the same row, from here on subtract start_time and End_time for the value...

```
    SELECT 
    ProductID 
    ,TransID 
    ,TransSubID
    , TIMEID START_TIME
    , Lead(TIMEID,1,0) OVER(Partition BY ProductID ORDER BY transid,TransSubID , TIMEID) END_TIME
    FROM your_table
order by ProductID,TransID,TransSubID
```

Comment: I'd say `OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY TimeID)`

Comment: This is working as far as giving me a start and end time per TransID. I really need TransID 58 as the start time and the next TransID 80 as the end time. I tried a where clause using TransID 58 and 80, but it's not returning the results I'd hoped for. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I updated the query to pick the next value based on transid and timeid.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
SELECT A.ProductID, A.TransID, A.TransSubID, B.timeID-A.TimeID 
FROM TableName A
INNER JOIN tableName B 
ON A.Product_ID = B.Product_ID
  AND A.TransID < B.TransID
  AND A.timeID < B.TimeID
  And B.TimeID = (SELECT min(timeID) 
                  FROM tableName 
                  WHERE ProductID = B.ProductID 
                    and TransID = B.TransID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about putting the logic in the TIMEFROMPARTS line into a Function. I used the second CROSS APPLY just to get my seconds into a simpler form it is used 3 times in the TIMEFROMPARTS function.

```
SELECT t.ProductID, t.TransID, t.TransSubID, t.TimeID, 
        t2.TransID, t2.TransSubID, t2.TimeID, 
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.TimeID, t2.TimeID) 'IfYouWantHours',
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.TimeID, t2.TimeID) 'IfYouWantMinutes',
        TIMEFROMPARTS(d.seconds % 216000 / 3600, d.seconds % 216000 % 3600 / 60
            , d.seconds % 3600 % 60, 0,0) 'IfYouWantTime'
FROM tblTransit t
    -- Returns the first (based on the time) record with the same ProductID
    -- and TimeID greater than.
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ProductID, TransID, TransSubID, TimeID 
                FROM tblTransit 
                WHERE ProductID = t.ProductID 
                    AND TimeID > t.TimeID) t2
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, t.TimeID, t2.TimeID) seconds) d
```

Returns....

```
   ProductID   TransID     TransSubID  TimeID           TransID     TransSubID  TimeID           IfYouWantHours IfYouWantMinutes IfYouWantTime
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -------------- ---------------- ----------------
111         58          2           10:00:00.0000000 80          0           12:00:00.0000000 2              120              02:00:00
111         80          0           12:00:00.0000000 80          0           14:00:00.0000000 2              120              02:00:00
```